# How to get Ubuntu to display unicode supplementary characters?

Tags: fonts, browser, unicode

I have a standard desktop UI install of the latest Ubuntu distro and I'm trying to view this page: http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/supplementary-test.html.

However none of the text display properly. I have tested this on Windows 8 and I can see them just fine.

My locale output is as follows:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I have also found the terminal also doesn't display many unicode characters.

Comment: It's likely that the fonts you're using don't contain the necessary glyphs for the characters you want. You could try copying your font from Windows 8 and using it in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

The comment about the missing glyphs is correct.

I installed additional font packages, namely AR PL fonts Ukai & Uming:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-arphic-uming fonts-arphic-ukai
```

and now I can get most (though not all) of the characters displayed correctly.

There maybe better font packages out there but that's the best answer I have come to the conclusion of at this time.

Answer (score 0):

See the following [answer of "terdon on strike"](https://askubuntu.com/a/1111736) in the [other thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689607/how-do-i-resolve-missing-characters-in-my-unicode-font).

In short:

```
sudo apt install fonts-noto
```

solves your question, displaying all characters of that test site correctly.