# How do I resolve missing characters in my unicode font?

Tags: fonts, unicode

I have tried Firefox and Chrome and on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and there seems to be a sizeable chunk of Unicode characters that I cannot render.

[Here](https://codepoints.net/U+1F415) is one example, and [here](https://codepoints.net/U+1F355) is another example.

What is the best course of action to diagnose the root cause and fix the missing characters?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Install package ttf-ancient-fonts.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ttf-ancient-fonts
```

Comment: Wow, this worked surprising well! My missing character was ⮡ (down-right arrow), and after installing this package, it just appeared in my Firefox tab where it was missing, without even reloading Firefox or the tab.

Answer (score 32):

The most comprehensive font package I have found is `font-noto`. Installing this has always fixed whatever font-display issues I was having:

```
sudo apt install fonts-noto
```

Then, restart your browser and everything should work as expected.

Comment: This fixed my problem with specific characters when `ttf-ancient-fonts` and `symbola` did not.

Comment: And for those on Fedora, this downloads massive amounts of fonts, to cover almost all missing Unicode characters: `sudo dnf install google-noto-*`

Comment: 680MB uncompressed on Ubuntu 21.04, but it did contain [my symbol of interest from Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f5d6/index.htm).

Answer (score 5):

In order to see the missing characters, you need to install a font which contains them.

I've found that [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) contains the best range of characters.

- Download the zip file.
- Install the two `.ttf` fonts - if you double click on then, you should see a font preview, click the "Install" button.

With the latest version (8.0.0) I'm able to see the dog symbol  and the slice of pizza symbol .

See: [image].

Comment: Or just `sudo apt-get install fonts-symbola` and then restart firefox ;)

Answer (score 4):

I managed to fix the unrecognized characters issue I was having on Linux by installing the following packages:

`apt-get install xfonts-unifont ttf-unifont`

(The above command assume a Debian system, for other distributions you may need to use another package manager and/or specific package names).

Comment: This solved my issue with the character "".

Answer (score 1):

For me, installing the `fonts-noto-cjk`, `fonts-noto-color-emoji`, `fonts-noto-core`, `fonts-noto-extra`, `fonts-noto-mono` and `fonts-noto-ui-core` installed the missing characters. Those fonts have a large unicode coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to view the characters on my computer (See signs and symbols). Enter the Unicode-code in the search-window. It looks that the symbols mentioned are not rendered yet (These characters are in the Supplementary Multilingual Plane). See also http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/unicode-sample-3-2.html.

File a bug in https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=gucharmap[image]

Comment: How do I obtain the Supplementary Multilingual Plane in Ubuntu?

Comment: on the console this would be `gucharmap`

Answer (score 0):

[Gentium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentium) fonts should cover everything.

There are basically 2 main  packages `fonts-sil-gentium` and `fonts-sil-gentiumplus`