# Unicode characters missing

Tags: command-line, fonts, unicode

I can't get my terminal (and python) to properly display some Unicode characters, mainly the new bitcoin symbol. The output is a box.

> > > $ echo -e \\u20bf
> > >
> > > [image: Output]

My terminal settings are default Ubuntu GNOME 16.10, the system is updated. I also tried changing the font to Noto/Noto Sans, but the character in question is still missing.

EDIT: Looking for a font patch for new accepted Unicode symbols 'in the pipeline' - [Proposed New Characters](http://unicode.org/alloc/Pipeline.html)?

Comment: Do you mean ฿ or ƀ? Where did you find that the bitcoin symboml was `u20bf`

Comment: Can you see it here in this list http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: Yes. Under currency symbols [http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8352](http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8352)

Comment: I see now that it's going to be included in a future package [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin#Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin#Units). Question reformulation: any font patches for Mono Regular or another font to show these symbols?

Comment: Would `Ƀ`, `฿`, `ƀ`, or `B͈̎` do the job?

Comment: Yes. I could work with B͈̎. What is the code for it?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem, and today this worked for me:

```
sudo apt install fonts-noto
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/1111736/292470

---

As a **side note**: while researching this, I found a way to insert unicode characters in GUI applications as well: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, then <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Source: [How can I type a Unicode character (for example, em-dash —?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31258/how-can-i-type-a-unicode-character-for-example-em-dash)