# Font "Ubuntu" is missing the U+26B7 Chiron Unicode Character

Tags: fonts

It seems like the default font "Ubuntu" is missing the character "⚷" Which makes smartgit to fallback to the next font "Noto" which has a strange line-height, so all commit lines with that kind of "key" icon are half a line off to the bottom:

[image]

We found out that the Noto font is used as replacement for the Ubuntu font with

```
FC_DEBUG=4 pango-view --font=Ubuntu -t "⚷ testString"
```

The problem comes from 26b7 being almost twice as high as regular text:
81x17 = GC.stringExtent("X test string")
80x31 = GC.stringExtent("⚷ test string")

The entire font 'Noto Sans Symbols' is bigger then its regular counterpart 'Noto Sans'.

How do I add the missing character to the "Ubuntu" font? Or where do I have to complain about the missing icon?

Note: I have installed the package `kubuntu-settings-desktop` which maybe caused Noto to be the fallback font.

**Update:**
I installed `gucharmap` with which I can view all installed fonts search for the CHIRON character (⚷) and it is not there (You need to enable 'View' -> 'Show only glyphs from this font').

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/689607/how-do-i-resolve-missing-characters-in-my-unicode-font check if helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems no easy solution. But at least it is fixed in SmartGit 20.2 now.

As a **Workaround** you could disable the "Noto Sans Symbols" font with

```
sudo mkdir /root/fonts-backup/
sudo mv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansSymbols* /root/fonts-disabled/
```

to restore the font, restore from the backup folder or reinstall with

```
sudo dpkg -l |grep noto|grep ii|cut -d" " -f 3 | xargs sudo apt install --reinstall
```